# Fast algorithm for the MATLAB's $\tt impz$ function?

Tags: matlab, impulse-response, reference-implementation

- Does anybody here know what is the code algorithm behind the `impz` function?
- I know it uses the recursive algorithm but how is such implemented in `impz` that it can get the impulse response of very high $N$ and $M$ orders (numerator and denominator coefficients)?

I can make a script that gets the impulse response of a second order LCCDE (linear constant coefficient differential equation) but I want to know a GENERAL code that can get the impulse response of any LCCDEs regardless of their order.

Comment: Is this a Matlab function? Perhaps give some background for those who dont' know the particularities of the function?

Comment: yes. The impz function generates the impulse response of ANY n order of a filter given its numerator and denominator. I want to know how is this to be implemented in a self made code. All I can do is just the impulse response of a 2nd order filter since it's just manual indexing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, [again](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35927/checking-my-function-versus-cconv-or-filter#comment68481_35927), this is a question easily answerable by the "Algorithm" section in [the official Matlab docs](https://en.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/impz.html).

Comment: @MarcusMüller the **question** is not something about matlab documentation but about a **fast** implementation of an esixting function. It may not be the most exciting question but I belive it makes sense to ask it. As you already know **matlab** is a valid and legal **tag** here...

Comment: @Fat32 "Does anybody here know what is the code algorithm behind the impz function?" certainly is a question answered in the docs. The question how to do it fast is only in the title, and I interpret the question in a manner that OP asks how the `impz` function is so fast

Comment: Mr. @MarcusMüller,  as far as I know the actual implementation code behind any of those low level (commercial) matlab functions is not documented anywhere. What is documented is the input and output interface and sometimes a simple mathematical description of the algorithm that was used to produce the result. So if he really wants that **code** then you are right and the question shall be closed. Otherwise if he is satisfied with an **algorithm** to produce the result, then we shall consider it as a valid question... My latest opinion however is towards your claim.

Comment: @Fat32 I'm not sure impz isn't high-level. I'm currently not at any computer with a matlab installation, but I think I remember a file impz.m in the signal toolbox. Anyway, still the "More about" section actually explains what the function does, https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/impz.html, and that matches the old code I found [here](https://github.com/rikrd/matlab/tree/master/signal/signal)(which very probably shouldn't be there).

Comment: @MarcusMüller impz() is possibly not a low level function whose proof is my answer ;-) What is low level is the **filter** function or the **fft** kind of core functions.

Answer (score 2):

the impz function of matlab, simply computes N samples of the impulse response of a given LTI system from its LCCDE description coefficients **a** nd **b**.
As far as I know its efficiency is a secondary issue, since computing an impulse response in real time is not a frequently encountered task.

One equivalent code is simply this:

```
  % given a,b vectors and number of samples as N
  x = [1 zeros(1,N-1)];
  h = filter(b,a,x);
```

I guess you know how the **filter** function is implemented and what its output means. In the simplest terms, the filter() matlab function computes the output vector **y** for an input vector **x** of an LTI system: $ \sum_{k=0}^{k=N}a_k y[n-k] = \sum_{k=0}^{k=M} b_k x[n-k]$ , by the **recursive** approach:

$$ y[n] = - \sum_{k=0}^{k=N} \frac{a_k}{a_0} y[n-k] + \sum_{k=0}^{k=M} \frac{b_k}{a_0} x[n-k] $$

Where the initial conditions of the system is assumed to be zero, inline with impulse response definition and LTI system with initial rest conditions.

Note that in the **impulse response** computation, the signal $x[n]$ has only a single nonzero entry at $n=0$ and the rest of the computation is a recursion on the signal $y[n]$ alone.

Comment: Thank you! Can I use freqz to find the impulse response of a given filter? I mean from freqz what can I do to retreive the impulse response?

Comment: This is "signal processing" stack exchange, not "teach me how to read matlab documentation and examples", sorry.

Comment: Yes you **can** use *freqz()* to find out the impulse response from given **b**,**a** vectors. It's pretty straightforward, as *freqz()* produces the first half of the Frequency Response $H(e^{j\omega})$ from $\omega =0$ to $\omega = \pi$ , you should first convert that into the full spectrum from $\omega =0$ to $\omega = 2\pi$  and perform an inverse FFT of appropriate length to get the proper impulse response $h[n]$ . As Marcus states such details can get out of the theory of signal processing however. Nevertheless **matlab** is a legal **tag** here and some questions are sure to be allowed

Comment: Thank you!! How many n points should I use in y= freqz(b,a,n,'whole')? And what if I want to get 100 samples of the impulse response. Should I use fft(y, 100)? Sorry if I question too much. i tried doing y = freqz(b,a,100,'whole') to divide the WHOLE circle by 100. Then do ifft(y,100) to get 100 h(n) samples but the results is different when I used impz(b.a).

Comment: you shall consider issues involved in FFT and inverse FFT usage and the signal lengths...

Comment: Can anyone help me retrieve the impulse response of a filter by USING freqz command and NOT impz command? I know that when you use freqz, its answer will be the H(W). So by using IDFT on H(W) I can retrieve h(n).

Example I want 100 samples of the impulse response of the filter described by the lccde y(n)-3y(n-1) = x(n). I would input [H,~] = freqz(1,[1 -3],100,'whole').  So I would use [Y] = ifft(H',100) function to inverse fourier the H(w) to h(n) using 100 samples to obtain 100 samples. But checking the answer using [i,~] = impz(1,[1 -3],100) would net a very FAR result. Please help me